# Is it possible to run code without gui on android?

Tags: python, android

I got python code that has no GUI and works in terminal. Can I convert it to apk and run on android?

I'm just curious if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot directly run a Python script in the terminal as an Android app. Python scripts are typically run on a computer using the Python interpreter, and Android devices use the Android operating system which is different from the typical computer operating systems.

However, you can use a tool such as Kivy, which is a Python library for creating mobile apps, to create an Android app from your Python script. Kivy provides a way to package your Python code into an Android app, so you can run it on an Android device.

I am sure there are other tools providing this option as well. These tools essentially bundle the Python interpreter and your script into a single executable file, so the user doesn't need to have Python installed on their device to run your app.

I believe there are tutorials on youtube as well so as to how to use Kivy to run your python code. I hope this helps :)